# Selectively merge Excel rows and delete original rows

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-2011

I have a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet (Mac 2011).

1. Some rows have data in columns A, C, D, E, F, and G. I will call these rows PARENT rows.
2. Other rows have data only in column B. I will call them CHILD rows. Each CHILD row is actually a subset of the PARENT row above it.
3. Each PARENT row has anywhere between 1 to 20 CHILD rows below it.
4. The pattern usually is: PARENT ROW, several CHILD ROWS below it, then another PARENT ROW, several CHILD ROWS below it, then another PARENT ROW, etc.

I am trying to:

[a] Copy the contents of each PARENT row and add them to the CHILD rows below it.

[b] Once copied, delete the original PARENT row.

There are more than 40,000 rows in the spreadsheet, and I don't know how to create a macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need a macro (but I have provided one at bottom)

*[Pls note this is a working solution for Excel on Windows - I have no experience with Excel for Macs so cannot guarantee that either or both the solutions below will work for you]*

**Manual Solution**

1. Select Columns A, C, D and E (esnure you select column A first)
2. Press F5 .... Goto Special and select Blanks and then hit "ok"
3. In the formula bar, type =A1 where A1 is the cell **immediately above** the first blank cell from step 2 (see picture below, this cell is A1)
4. Press the *Ctrl* and *Enter* keys together.  You now have the correct data in the child rows
5. Select columns A:E and Copy then Paste Special as Values to convert the formulae you just entered in the child rows to values
6. Select Column B
7. Press F5 .... Goto Special and select Blanks and then hit "ok" (see pic below)
8. Delete the seleted rows

[image: Step 3]
[image: Step 7]

**Code Solution**

```
Sub Delete()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = Range("A:A,C:E").SpecialCells(xlBlanks)
On Error GoTo 0
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
rng1.Formula = "=R[-1]C"
'handles two row areas else SpecialCells will force both areas to area1 formulae
For Each rng2 In rng1.Areas
rng2.Value = rng2.Value
Next rng2
On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlBlanks)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then rng1.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. The manual solution is not working - I get a response "Selection is too large." To run the code, should I select Sheet1 or ThisWorkBook from the project tree list in the Excel VB Editor?

Comment: When I tried to run it in Sheet1, I got an error message: "Compile error: Member already exists in an object module from which this object module derives." When I tried running it in the ThisWorkBook editor window, all cells in columns A, C, D, and E turned into some kind of #Ref! value.

Comment: So I tried doing this on a PC (just in case Excel was playing up on Mac). When I try the manual method, only the first set of empty cells in column A got selected, while all empty cells in the other selected columns were selected. However, when I put in =A2 (the first cell above the empty cell) it filled only A3. All other cells remained selected, but empty. :(

Comment: OK, I am an idiot. I forgot to press Ctrl while pressing enter. Selected just one column, hit F5 > Special > blanks and followed your instructions, and it worked! Thanks! (Only a couple of cells are getting selected when I select other columns, which I assume is some problem with Excel.)